# Programmatically Built Buttons Don't Appear in MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, button, binding, code-behind

**Background**

I have an MVVM skeleton for a Risk game learning project. I have decided to attempt creating parts of the UI programmatically for both "convenience"/elegance and as a learning opportunity. The parts in question are custom Buttons that represent the game board's Territories and should, eventually, take in most of the user's input.

**Pivotal Choice**

A source of complication: My attempt to leverage a global Enum (TerrID_Enum.cs), which seemed like a logical move since the game Board is static. Each Territory receives an int ID number from 0 - 41. This then allows me to use arrays and for loops with the indices correlating directly to the appropriate Territory, in whichever frame (Model, VM, View). (As I said, a *global* Enum). I've seen different takes about this both here and elsewhere online, so feel free to chime in about it if you think there's something about this choice you think I need to know.

**Custom Method for Building Binding Paths out of the For-Loop Index / Territory Enum relationship**

As you will see, the programmatic initializer for the Buttons relies on a custom Method for writing the Binding Paths (Board.MakeStringPath()). It seems to work up to a point -- the Path.Data property inside of the custom Button's Content Grid gets the right Geometry at first -- but then after IntializeComponent() it appears to go to null? Beyond this, the ActualHeight and ActualWidth properties of both the bound Paths and the custom Buttons sit at 0 for some reason, and I don't know how this is related but it seems to be.

**Most Relevant Code Snippets:**

This is what my MainWindow.xaml and MainWindow.cs include. I've omitted a few Triggers and miscellaneous stuff for clarity:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="TerrButtonCT" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            Board VM = new(NewGame);

            this.DataContext = VM;

            Canvas mainCanvas = new Canvas();
            this.AddChild(mainCanvas);
            Button[] TerrButtons = new Button[42];

            // Programatic creation and detail of the Territory Buttons
            for (int index = 0; index < 42; index++)
            {
                // "Content" Grid and Shape, with associated Bindings, are created
                Grid defaultGrid = new Grid();
                
                Binding terrButtonPathData = new(VM.MakePathString(index, nameof(VM.Shapes)));
                terrButtonPathData.Source = VM;

                Binding terrButtonFill = new(VM.MakePathString(index, nameof(VM.Color)));
                terrButtonFill.Source = VM;

                Path terrPath = new Path() { Stretch = Stretch.Fill };
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(terrPath, Path.DataProperty, terrButtonPathData);
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(terrPath, Path.FillProperty, terrButtonFill);

                defaultGrid.Children.Add(terrPath);

                // Control Template brought in from Window Resources
                ControlTemplate buttonCT = (ControlTemplate)this.Resources["TerrButtonCT"];

                // Triggers 
                
                // Multi-Trigger for Mouse "Hover" behavior
                MultiTrigger hoverTrigger = new MultiTrigger();

                hoverTrigger.Conditions.Add(new() { Property = IsMouseOverProperty, Value = true} );
                hoverTrigger.Conditions.Add(new() { Property = Button.IsPressedProperty, Value = false }); ;

                // Setters for Trigger details. Shape and Fill need to be bound just like "Content"
                hoverTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter() { Property = BackgroundProperty, Value = null });
                hoverTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter() { Property = BorderBrushProperty, Value = null });

                Path hoverPath = new() { Stretch = Stretch.Fill };
                Binding hoverColor = new Binding(VM.MakePathString(index, nameof(VM.HoverColor)));
                hoverColor.Source = VM;
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(hoverPath, Path.DataProperty, terrButtonPathData);
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(hoverPath, Path.FillProperty, hoverColor);

                Grid hoverGrid = new Grid();
                hoverGrid.Children.Add(hoverPath);

                hoverTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter() { Property = ContentProperty, Value = hoverGrid });


                // Wrap everything into an individualized Style for the Button
                Style buttonStyle = new Style();
                buttonStyle.Triggers.Add(hoverTrigger);
                
                buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter() { Property = ContentProperty, Value = defaultGrid });
                buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter() { Property = TemplateProperty, Value = buttonCT });

                // Feed custom details to the Button
                TerrButtons[index] = new Button
                {
                    Name = ((TerrID)index).ToString(),
                    Style = buttonStyle
                };
                // Add each Button to the MainWindow Child Canvas
                mainCanvas.Children.Add((TerrButtons[index]));
            }

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the ViewModel so far:

```
internal class Board : ViewModelBase
    {
        
        private ObservableCollection<SolidColorBrush> _color;
        private ObservableCollection<SolidColorBrush> _hoverColor;
        

        public Board(Game newGame)
        {
            CurrentGame = newGame;

            Shapes = new List<Geometry>();
            Color = new ObservableCollection<SolidColorBrush>();
            HoverColor = new ObservableCollection<SolidColorBrush>();

            for (int index = 0; index < BaseArmies.Count; index++)
            {
                if (Application.Current.FindResource(((TerrID)index).ToString() + "Geometry") != null)
                    Shapes.Add(Application.Current.FindResource(((TerrID)index).ToString() + "Geometry") as Geometry);

                Color.Add(Brushes.Black);
                HoverColor.Add(Brushes.AntiqueWhite);
            }
        }
        public List<Geometry> Shapes { get; init; }

        public ObservableCollection<SolidColorBrush> Color
        {
            get { return _color; }
            set
            {
                _color = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Color));
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<SolidColorBrush> HoverColor
        {
            get { return _hoverColor; }
            set
            {
                _hoverColor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HoverColor));
            }
        }

...

        internal string MakePathString(int index, string propertyName)
        {
            if (index >= 0 && index < 42 && propertyName != null)
            {
                string indexStr = index.ToString();

                switch (propertyName) 
                {
                    case nameof(Color):
                        return "Color[" + indexStr + "]";
                    case nameof(HoverColor):
                        return "HoverColor[" + indexStr + "]";
                    case nameof(PressedColor):
                        return "PressedColor[" + indexStr + "]";
                    case nameof(DisabledColor):
                        return "DisabledColor[" + indexStr + "]";
                    case nameof(Shapes):
                        return "Shapes[" + indexStr + "]";
                }
                return "Property not found!";
            }
            else return "MakePathString() requires 0 < int index < 42 and string propertyName.";
        }
```

**Further Code / Notes**

In addition to the global TerrID Enum, there is a massive App.xaml with Geometries for each of the Territories. I don't believe it's necessary to include here, but you can find it on Github.

The basic design for customizing a Button with a Path as its shape was adapted/lifted from [here.](https://sl-alex.net/gui/2021/07/29/custom_button_wpf/)

If need to see more: [Full Project @ Github](https://github.com/LivingCryogen/RiskMVVM2)

Nuget Package included: MS MVVM Community Toolkit 8.2.0

**Thanks!**

I know this is a lot to go through, so thanks in advance!

**Past Attempts and Frustration**

I've tried setting a custom Button Style in XAML, but I want to create a custom Path string to enable the for-loop initializer and this would require either nested Bindings (A Binding on Binding.Path, which I discovered doesn't work because it's not a DependencyProperty), or some elaborate work with DataObjectProvider which I have yet to wrap my head around. (I also ditched a series of Converters as unworkable, but that might be a solution, I just don't see it).

Comment: RuleOfThumb: Whenever your ViewModel uses a UI type, you did something wrong. Think of a UI designer who has to design the UI but is not allowed to modify the ViewModel. Just tell him in the Viewmodel that something is hit, occupied, broken or lost or what kind values can be set or what kind of actions may happen. Now the UI designer can fully design how the UI will present that to the User.

Comment: Wpf is biased toward MVVM, using things like listView/listBox and templates to represent dynamic list of things. So I would reconsider your plan to write the UI from code behind, I do not think it will be a particular useful thing to learn. Or possibly, use winforms instead, since that is more amendable to constructing the UI from code.

Comment: Doing this is on code is just the harder more painfiull way to aaproach things. instead of creating all these thing in code create a custom Control and add these dynamically. All triggers, logic and annimations can be done in the control itself

Comment: @SirRufo I think I understand that the View and ViewModel are kept somewhat separate. But I'm unclear on which "View type" is being used in this ViewModel. As far as I can tell the only only thing the View needs to know is the property Name and the Territory ID (from the global Enum); it would need to know the property Name for binding purposes anyway, right? And all that the ViewModel gets from the View here is an int index and property name of its own property.

Comment: @JonasH I appreciate that. My fallback plan is to hard code 42 individual controls. My current plan is only to programmatically create the custom buttons, as this allows me to create the custom Binding Path string.

Comment: @jmcknight00 [`SolidColorBrush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush) or [`Geometry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.geometry) both from `PresentationCore.dll`

Comment: @DenisSchaf I forgot to mention I did try a custom control, building it from the ground up. But I ran into the same issue that this programmatic creation is trying to solve: how to utilize the array of the Model (or the Lists of the ViewModel) in the Bindings for the Controls. So, a bespoke TerritoryControl would still need its Shape (Path.Data) and Color (Player Owner Color) to be Bound to the corresponding ViewModel entries, with Paths like "Shapes[3]" and "Color[3]", but to get the appropriate index dynamically seems to be a problem. Without Binding to a Path, how would this be done?

Comment: @SirRufo Oh, OK, I understand the Types you mean now. But I thought the point of the ViewModel was to "format" the information in a way useful to the View? If not by converting the Model info into Lists of such Types, what is the ViewModel supposed to be doing here, and how does the Binding work without using such Types?

Comment: @jmcknight00 I told you already in my first comment.

Comment: @SirRufo If so, I don't understand how.

Comment: @jmcknight00 The part with the UI designer?

Comment: @SirRufo I'll have to figure out how the general point applies to the specifics here. Thanks.

Comment: @jmcknight00 Have a look at [this example](https://gist.github.com/SirRufo/0cbb92167bce794bbdf804a6cfc4be6c) of a Minesweeper in WPF (only View and ViewModel). All of the design is in the view and the game logic is in the ViewModel and below

Comment: I think a large part of the problem is that WPF has a fairly steep learning curve. It is not obvious how to use styles/templates etc in an effective way. And the tooling, error reporting etc could certainly be better. Unfortunately I do not have a good solution, studying some examples should certainly help.